# Tensorflow Define Op Polymorphic on Fully Defined vs not Fully Defined Shape

Tags: tensorflow

If I am defining a custom Op in Tensorflow, is it possible to provide two Kernels for the top that are polymorphic on whether the shape for the inputs are fully defined? For example, I can construct certain structures once at Kernel construction if the shape is fully known / defined.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to do this. The [kernel dispatch mechanism](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2d23960e29c3efb1b30c5cb6f8f3368635b97f29/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc#L998) is implemented in a low-level part of the TensorFlow code where information about tensor shapes is not (generally) available.

However, the ability to specialize a graph based on known shapes does seem like a useful ability, and it might be worth raising this as a feature request on the [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues). One possible workaround would be to try [registering an optimization pass](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2d23960e29c3efb1b30c5cb6f8f3368635b97f29/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/optimization_registry.h) that makes use of shape information and rewrites the names of ops with known input shapes to a different op that relies on static shape information (e.g. via an additional attr). However, doing this in TensorFlow currently requires you to rebuild from source.

Comment: If the shape for the input have been set on the Tensor, how do you access them from the `OpKernelConstruction`?

Comment: Posted as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42771865/access-input-shape-from-opkernel-constructor-opkernelconstruction